# Determining cool numbers?

Tags: java

I'm working on a program which determines a cool number. A cool number is any number that has a remainder of 1 when divided by 3,4,5, and 6. The method iscoolNum will determine if a number is a cool number. The method countCoolNumbers will count the number of cool numbers between 6 and the parameter passed in. Here's an example of what I have so far in the class:

```
import static java.lang.System.*;

public class CoolNumbers
```

{

```
public static boolean isCoolNumber( int num )
{ 
     int x; 
    x = 6;
    for(x = 6; x<num; x++)
    {
    if ((x%3==1)  &&  (x%4==1)  && (x%5 ==1) && (x%6 == 1))

        return true;

    }
     return false;
}


public static int countCoolNumbers( int stop )
{
     boolean check=isCoolNumber(stop);
     int b=0;
  for(b=0;b<stop;b++);
   {
    if(check==true)
    {

    }
    else
    {
        b=b-1;
    }
 return b;

}
```

}
}

The code in the main:

```
import static java.lang.System.*;

public class CoolNumbersRunner
```

{

```
public static void main( String[] args )
{

    System.out.println( CoolNumbers.countCoolNumbers(250) + " cool numbers between 6 - " + 250);
    //add more test cases
}
```

}

The problem I have is when i run the program, the output is "250 cool numbers between 6-250" whereas it should only be 4 cool numbers through 6-250. I cant quite figure out how to properly use the for loop and such. Sorry if some things seem off, Im very new to Java. Thanks in advance

Comment: `isCoolNumber` shouldn't have a loop. It could be one line `return ((num%3==1)  &&  (num%4==1)  && (num%5 ==1) && (num%6 == 1));`.

Comment: how would i set that to return true or false?

Comment: Thought of a question - is it a requirement to use `for` loops? Is the intent of this exercise to learn about the `for` loop construct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than give away the answer right away I'll refer you to the tutorial page for the `for` statement, [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) and I'll point out the following:

Your `countCoolNumbers` only calls `isCoolNumber` once since the call is not inside of a loop.

You have an error in `countCoolNumbers` here: `for(b=0;b<stop;b++);` in that you probably didn't intend to have no logic inside the loop, but that is what you did by placing a semicolon after the `for`.

`isCoolNumber` could be written to use a loop or it could be written without one. The loop would be used to generate the second parameter to the modulus - 3,4,5,6. The way you have it written it has half of each approach and does not accomplish your goal. Remember the purpose of the method is to determine whether a single number (the parameter) is a "cool number" or not. You then call this method repeatedly giving it different values for its parameter.

**EDIT:**

**Other Thoughts:**

You're going to want to test your code thoroughly once you're done making changes. To do that I'd suggest you take some time to think about what it means from a mathematical point of view for a number to have a remainder of 1 when divided by 3,4,5,6 and how you could build test data that would convince you that your code works correctly.

Comment: You're welcome and if you post your revised code as an edit to your question I'll be happy to help some more.